# How to inject a header from the errormessage

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've been attempting to inject a custom header for a error response status (and failing).

I have a very simple lambda being used

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   // TODO implement

   //callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');

   var error = {
       name:"error", 
       message:"I am a failure",
       statusCode: 400
   };

   error["x-test"] = 'foo';

   callback(JSON.stringify(error), null);
};
```

In the api gateway, I've done the following:

set up CORS to include x-test
responsetemplate = `"$input.path('$.errorMessage')"`
responseparameter to include:

```
method.response.header.x-test = integration.response.body.x-test
```

Also, I have a statusCode mapped using `'.*statusCode.*?400.*'`

This has turned out empty.

so I decided to take a step back and see what happens if I do:

```
method.response.header.x-test = integration.response.body
```

I found that I get the stringified response of errorMessage.

```
{"x-test":"{\"errorMessage\":\"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"error\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"I am a failure\\\",\\\"statusCode\\\":400,\\\"x-test\\\":\\\"foo\\\"}\"}"}
```

So I decided to change the responsetemplate to force it to json by doing the following:

responsetemplate = `"$util.parseJson($input.path('$.errorMessage'))"`

and I still get the stringified response:

```
{"x-test":"{\"errorMessage\":\"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"error\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"I am a failure\\\",\\\"statusCode\\\":400,\\\"x-test\\\":\\\"foo\\\"}\"}"}
```

My guess is that it doesn't transform as expected, but only for the final output.

So how would you take a value and shove it into a header?

Thanks,
Kelly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you are stringifying the error object coming from your Lambda function. API Gateway attempts to resolve the JSON-Path expression and can't evaluate "x-test" in a string. If you return an object instead of a string, this should work.

You may want to consider using [proxy integrations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-set-up-lambda-proxy-integration-on-proxy-resource) which allow you to control the headers and status directly from your Lambda function.

Update: I've written a blog post on this topic with sample code @ https://rpgreen.wordpress.com/2017/01/25/how-to-send-response-headers-for-aws-lambda-function-exceptions-in-api-gateway/

Comment: Hi Ryan, it looks like the proxy is a wildcard. Is there a way to restrict it?

Comment: Not currently, but you can combine proxy paths with static parent/children resources

Comment: Thanks Ryan for all your help. It seems like this is the only option. While I do understand the design behind it. It's really a shame that it's locked down to not allow transforming of headers using the errormessage. AWS gives you all this flexibility and then they decide to make that not an option. The reason why it would be great is we want to output a unique identifier for our whole transaction or request/response stream, which is similar to aws', but spans for our chained microservice requests.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more of a design choice regarding the limitation imposed by both Lambda and APIGateway. I will try my best to walk through my thoughts.

First of all, in Lambda, **callback(error, result)** function can either take an error *string* as first argument, or an *object* as result response. If you want to pass along a simple error message, you could definitely just do that. However, in your case, as you tried to pass along an entire error object, choosing the second option is clearly a better solution (in contrast to stringifying an object and parse it into object again). As a result, the final line of your Lambda function should be:

`callback(null, error);`

Yes, in this case, if you test your function in Lambda, the output result will no longer be red and flag it as an error, but this won't matter as you can format your headers and response in APIGateway.

Now you need to set things up in APIGateway, in which you need to make use of the object passed by Lambda.

[image]
It's actually rather easy to use method execution interface to configure headers.

- In **Method Response**, you need to add the headers you want to include in the response for a specific status code, which in your case is **x-test**. (If you want the API to return different status codes, you can also configure that in this panel.)
- Then go to **Integration Response**, under the same status code, you will see the added header available. According to [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html) documentation from AWS, you can use `integration.response.body.JSONPath_EXPRESSION` to assign the header value (this is another reason that you should return object rather than string in Lambda, as there is no formal API to parse object from string at this stage). This time, as your Lambda is passing an object, the value of **x-test** header is:

`integration.response.body['x-test']`

- Now your API should have the proper header included.

**NOTE**: <strike>In order to set up different status code in APIGateway, you should leave some distinguishable data fields (your statusCode: 400 should work perfectly) in you response body, so you can use RegEx to match those fields to a specific status code.</strike>

So... above doesn't work with success message. I found this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/error-handling-patterns-in-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/) though talking about error handling design pattern. Apparently what they suggest is only mapping status code when there is an error, in which case no body should be passed (only the errorMessage), as browser won't care about response body for a status code other than 200 anyway.

I guess after all, it is impossible to customize both status code and header at the same time with Lambda passing an object to APIGateway?

Comment: I was going doing the same path as you `callback(null, error);` 

1. thank you!
2. I am really trying to determine the issue / if any with making that the direction (complications etc...)
3. thank you again :)

Comment: So it looks like there is an issue if I try to make it a success all the time (by passing the error object). I can't seem to map the 400 over. From what I read the lambda regex to bind integration responses to responses is only for errorMessage property. Is there another way to handle this with success statements?

Comment: You can do this with errors but you will be restricted to sending only the header value as a string in the callback, and then mapping using 'integration.response.body.errorMessage'. See second example in https://rpgreen.wordpress.com/2016/01/04/how-to-http-redirects-with-api-gateway-and-lambda/

Comment: @KellyTheDev I think you are right, I guess the conclusion is that you can't customized status code (but you can customize header) if you pass an object from Lambda to APIGateway. On the other hand, you can customize status code (not possible for header) if you pass error message.